# ServerSelectionTimeoutError: Got opcode 1598575443 but expected 1: While querying MongoDB thorugh Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here's the code I'm using. Pymongo version == 2.8

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://username:password@:port")
db = client.database
collection = db['document']
collection.count()
```

I would appreciate your help a lot. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're connecting to a server that is *not* MongoDB. I know that the connection string you included in your question, "mongodb://username:password@:port", is not the string you're actually using, since it's invalid and MongoClient() would raise an error. Whatever your actual connection string is, double-check it. I suspect your port is wrong. If your MongoDB server is listening on the default port, 27017, try a string like this:

"mongodb://username:password@host:27017"

Replace username, password, and host with your server's actual values.